# Load content with AJAX and animation - jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need your help!

I need some help to add some animation for my code. Now it works like - 
Click on link -> fade in text -> click on another link -> fade out current text -> fade in new text.

What I want is like this - **Click on link** -> #content animates down to xx:px (depending on content height that loads in) -> fade in text -> **Click on link** -> current text fades out and #content animates up -> #content animates down  to xx:px (depending on content height that loads in) -> fade in text

Here is the code so far...

> **Updated** here is the jsfiddle - but the ajax thing don´t work http://jsfiddle.net/jelm/7zLW5/2/
>   Or you can take a look at my test page http://landetdigital.se/olaselmen/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.menu li a').click(function() {

       $('#contentHolder').fadeOut("fast");
        var targetPage = $(this).attr('href');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#content').load(targetPage, function() {
            $('#contentHolder').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

 return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net sample so ppl can test and tweak easily.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using callbacks within fadeIn() and fadeOut().

If for example you want something done after `$('#contentHolder').fadeIn('slow')` you could do that in the following way:

```
$('#contentHolder').fadeIn('slow',function(){ 
    alert('#contentHolder was faded in!');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to get the right height of the new content is putting the just loaded content in an hidden div and retrieve the height of that. Then animate the shown div to the right height, and delete the temporary one.

Getting the height of a div with:

```
.css({ display: 'none' });
```

..is not going to work, use:

```
.css({'position':'absolute','visibility':'hidden', 'display':'block'});
```

..instead.